# Huggingface tokenizer not working properly when defined in a function / different program

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to add new tokens to Layoutxlm tokenizer ("microsoft/layoutxlm-base) and following is the code for the same.

```
model = LayoutLMv2ForRelationExtraction.from_pretrained("microsoft/layoutxlm-base")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/layoutxlm-base")

new_tokens = tokens

# check if the tokens are already in the vocabulary
new_tokens = set(new_tokens) - set(tokenizer.vocab.keys())

# add the tokens to the tokenizer vocabulary
tokenizer.add_tokens(list(new_tokens))
# add new, random embeddings for the new tokens
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
## Save the modified tokenizer

model.save_pretrained('layout_xlm_base_model')
tokenizer.save_pretrained('layout_xlm_base_tokenizer')

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('layout_xlm_base_tokenizer')
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(text = tokens, boxes = bboxes, is_pretokenized=False)
print(len(input_ids)) #
```

Prints 126 for given tokens 124 which is correct.

But when I define this same thing in a function or in a script it doesn't work

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, LayoutLMv2ForRelationExtraction

def add_tokens(tokens:list=None, tokenizer:AutoTokenizer=None, model:LayoutLMv2ForRelationExtraction=None):
    
    new_tokens = tokens

        # check if the tokens are already in the vocabulary
    new_tokens = set(new_tokens) - set(tokenizer.vocab.keys())

        # add the tokens to the tokenizer vocabulary
    tokenizer.add_tokens(list(new_tokens))
    
        # add new, random embeddings for the new tokens
    model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
    tokenizer.save_pretrained('layout_xlm_base_tokenizer')
    model.save_pretrained('layout_xlm_base_model')



add_tokens(tokens = tokens, tokenizer = tokenizer, model = model)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('layout_xlm_base_tokenizer')
model = LayoutLMv2ForRelationExtraction.from_pretrained('layout_xlm_base_model')
bboxes=bboxes
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(text = tokens, boxes = bboxes)
print(len(input_ids))
```

prints 248 which was before modification which is not intended

What am I missing?

Comment: "It doesn't work", how?

Comment: As I have put the comment in the last print statement. The output of no. of input_ids should be 126 and not 248. It outputs no. of input_ids as 248 when the new tokens are not added and it outputs 126  when the new tokens are added.